# How can you indicate the order in which DbConnection.GetSchema returns its values?

Tags: c#, ado.net, ado, vb6-migration

I am porting a VB6 database-centric application relying on ADO to C# (relying on ADO.NET). The schema of the databases this application access are arbitrary and I'm relying on `DbConnection.GetSchema` to retrieve information.

As near as I can tell (And here's where I need help), `GetSchema` is supposed to replace the ADOX.Catalog.  So here's what I have (sorry about the formatting!):

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();
string[] restrictions = new string[4] { null, null, tableName, null };
using (SqlConnection databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    databaseConnection.Open();
    foreach (DataRow row in databaseConnection.GetSchema(
                SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, restrictions).Rows)
    {
        temp.Add(row["COLUMN_NAME"] as string);
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that this correctly fills `temp` with the names of the columns for the table named `tableName`.  However, the order seems arbitrary, whereas with ADOX.Catalog the order is exactly the same as you'd find it in Sql Management Studio.  Here's how the original does it:

```
Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
Dim T As ADOX.Table
Dim C As ADOX.Column

Set cat.ActiveConnection = conn

'retrieve list of fields for this table'
Set T = cat.Tables(tableName)

For Each C In T.Columns
    temp.Add C.Name

Next
```

They come out in different orders, and I'm not sure what to do about it!

My question is basically: Does ADO.NET have a replacement for ADOX.Catalog other than GetSchema? If it doesn't how can I order GetSchema so that I don't get random ordering (it's going to confuse my co-workers who are using this so badly!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx) method to order the results:

```
databaseConnection.Open();
DataTable columns = databaseConnection.GetSchema(
            SqlClientMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, restrictions);
foreach (DataRow row in columns.Select("", "COLUMN_NAME"))
{
    temp.Add(row["COLUMN_NAME"] as string);
}
```